# Script - Is it possible to build an addresss that allows retrieve a certain amount per address?

Tags: script, wealth-distribution

Is it possible to define a multi signature address that allows spending only certain percentage to each signature?

For example, three different people with different public-private keys build an pay to script address with a script that allows spending only 34% of the total amount.

So instead of requiring multiple signatures to spend the amount, it define limits on each signature.

Comment: I think you could accomplish a similar result using a LN-style setup: create a multisig output and pass some partially-signed transactions around between the multisig participants, paying to with new outputs in the desired amounts.

Answer (score 1):

Each output can only be spent atomically. Either the entire amount or not at all.

The scripts are not evaluated for any “amount”. The script machine evaluates to true or false.

Of course, it is possible to spend this multisig output to multiple other outputs, each with a separate amount and output script (spending destination).

Comment: In that case, would it be possible to specify the amount that is sent to each address? Let's say, for specify that anyone the address is only expendable to those three addresses and should send 33% to each.